# Can't CTRL+Drag NSButton to custom NSView header

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder, nstableview, nsview, nstablecellview

I'd like to create a custom `NSTableCellView` instantiated by Interface Builder. I've set my Table Cell View class to `MyTableCellView`, and properly created `MyTableCellView : NSTableCellView` .m/.h files.

However, I just can't CTRL+Drag a simple button from inside this view to `MyTableCellView.h` in order to create an `IBOutlet`.

Here is a video to show what happens: http://youtu.be/sNNbuVT-SZs.

**How the view is subclassed:**

[image: NSTableCellView subclassed]

**How I try to CTRL+Drag a button**

[image: CTRL+Dragging a NSButton]

Also, sometimes, Interface Builder just don't allow the cell view's class to be modified. What's happening ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found a solution, that is a little weird but works as expected. Instead of connecting the `NSButton` to `MyTableCellView` header directly, I used the reversed path:

Manually create an outlet:

```
@property(retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSButton* button;
```

Then click the empty circle on the left, and drag it to your XIB file's button:

[image]

I have no idea why it works this way, please let me know if you know the anwser.

Comment: Did you try restarting Xcode? Sometimes it gets corrupted; perhaps that part that keeps track of file counterparts, xib owners, actions etc. Happened to me before with an OS X app.

Comment: Well, yes I did. Maybe like one hundred times ^^ There are a lot of weird bugs in Interface Builder, this is one of them.