# InterfaceBuilder NSButton connect to NSViewController Cause "Could not connect action, target class NSObject does not respond to"

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder, nstableview, nstableviewcell

I have a view-based `NSTableView` whose "file's owner" is the `ViewController`.
I dragged a button(for deletion) on the custom `NSTableCellView`, so I want to click the button and delete the current row from tableView, but when add a row the debug console tells me "`Could not connect action, target class NSObject does not respond to deleteAction:`"

I m using the NSArrayController binding the NSTableView(add action is triggered successfully). I also got another weird problem, I try to subclass `NSTableCellView` and set the cell's `"Custom Class"` to `MyTableCellView` but I can not connect the button to my MyTableCellView.

[image: Debugger]

[image: UI]

Comment: Did you set the class of the file's owner to the `ViewController` class?

Comment: @Willeke Thanks again, Yes, I did set the file' owner to ViewController, and I solved the button connect issue by this link [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11811765/cant-ctrldrag-nsbutton-to-custom-nsview-header?rq=1)

Comment: any luck? I am having the same problem :(